# Emailing Form in Access

Tags: forms, email, ms-access, vba

Im trying to figure out if its possible to email out a form based on the click of the command button. I created the form instead of a report because I want to view record separately and not a bunch at a time. Im now seeing its hard to email a form. I know how to make the report make an email with the command mail report button but does anyboyd know if there is a way to email a form?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `DoCmd.SendObject`.

http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/email/sendobject.html

The function uses the Default mail application as Outlook. To send a Form the code behind the button would be,

```
Private sub yourButtonName_Click()
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "yourFormName", acFormatPDF, "someone@somedomain.com"
End Sub
```

There are several arguments like **Cc**, **Bcc**, **MessageText** etc.

To overcome any errors that might occur when a user hits Cancel, you can make use of the On Error statement to handle the error. Something like,

```
Private sub yourButtonName_Click()
On Error GoTo errHandle
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "yourFormName", acFormatPDF, "someone@somedomain.com"
exitErr:
    Exit Sub
errHandle:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
        MsgBox "Error (" & Err.Number & ") - " & Err.Description & " Occurred."
    End If
    Resume exitErr
End Sub
```

You can look into C Pearson's website, to learn more on [Error Handling in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Comment: Do you know if there is a code that blocks the error message that pops up when the email is exited out of instead of sent. Like if somebody hits the button on accident and doesnt send the email I dont want an error to show.

Comment: You can make use of the On Error statement. Check out my edited post.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much!!! Everything is working great. Im just having an issue with the PDF thats being produced. It creating 20 duplicates of the same form. Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: I cannot comment without seeing what you have done so far. I would suggest you create a new thread, so the issue can be addressed properly.